# Храниение ссылок изображений

Tags: ссылки, php, интернет-магазин, mysql

Всем привет. Делаю свой первый интернет магазин. Как и где лучше хранить ссылки для изображений? Спасибо всем кто ответит.

Comment: в БД

Answer (score 6):

Могу рассказать, как делаю это я. Я не храню ссылки в БД, а прописываю для изображения имя, связанное с ID продукта. Например, если продукт в БД имеет ID 55, то несколько фотографий, относящихся к нему, имеют нзвания: 55_1.jpg, 55_2.jpg, 55_3.jpg и т.д. В этом случае, у вас не возникнет ситуации, когда имена фото разных товараов могут совпадать. Кроме того, легко менять конкретную фотографию товара и элементарно удалить их все, при удалении товара из БД

Comment: Очень интересный вариант. Спасибо

Comment: Мне тоже нравится, а для большого проекта так можно?

Comment: для большого проекта это не подойдет, поскольку каждый раз будут просматриваться и сравниваться имена файлов требуемым шаблоном. и это не хорошо. ведь не зря перешли от файловой схемы хранения данных к базам данных - чтобы абстрагироваться от действий с файлами.

Comment: @MuFF, для блоьших проектов, на мой взгляд, хранить изображения в БД в виде BLOB - это извращение. При таком способе, в случае запроса пользователем данных, они будут храниться в памяти. Не есть гуд.

Comment: По моему самый оптимальный способ. Паковка изображений в картинке привносит в проект значительное кол-во минусов.

Comment: а что, если раскидывать по папкам?, к примерук для продукта ID=55 в папке 55 будут лежать файлы 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg

Comment: @IVsevolod данное действие лишено смысла.

Comment: @Deonis, причем тут то что я написал в другой ветке? и про blob я написал, что это порождает трудности. а мы здесь твой метод обсуждаем. имя файла - это просто имя файла. это не место, где стоит оставлять метаданные. в будущем у тебя могут быть проблемы с масштабированием - имея информацию об изображениях в бд, мы бы просто создали поле, а в твоем случае придется мутить с папками. файловая система - она древовидная и не подходит для хранения данных, подразумевающих реляционность. этот способ легок для понимания начинающими.

Answer (score 2):

Само изображение можно загружать в базу в тип blob или binary, но это порождает еще больше трудностей. но в базе данных всеравно должна быть информация обо всей информации, в том числе и о картинках.

вместо blob лучше использовать следующий способ:

Заведи табличку, например files, с полями id и link. когда загружаешь файл, заводишь запись для него. а уже в других таблицах, например в товарах, указываешь идентификатор файла в таблице files.

Comment: > Заведи табличку, например files, с полями id и link. когда загружаешь файл, заводишь запись для него.

да!, думаю это важный момент, знать вообще откуда этот файл появился...

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

1. Кидайте все картинки в одну папку `image`
2. При загрузке генерируйте название файла в виде `nazvanie-kategorii-nazvanie-tovara-timestamp`
3. Название файла записывайте в базу данных